# How to add a blank line before the first line in a text file with awk

Tags: awk

I have some text files. I would like to add a blank line before the first line in each text file. How can I do this with awk?

Comment: Is awk a requirement? Or will any unix command chain work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would prefer `GNU sed` for this task:

**To add a space to the beginning of the file:**

```
sed '1s/.*/ &/' file.txt
```

To perform this on multiple text files with the `.txt` extension, and make the changes directly to the files (i.e. overwrite them), try:

```
sed -s -i '1s/.*/ &/' *.txt
```

**To add a blank line at the beginning of the file:**

```
sed '1i\\' file.txt
```

To perform this on multiple text files with the `.txt` extension, and make the changes directly to the files (i.e. overwrite them), try:

```
sed -s -i '1i\\' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your code doesn't work for multiple files.

Comment: @user1606106: Sorry, I forgot to add the `-i` flag. It should work now as expected. HTH.

Comment: You can drop the for loop and use `-s` instead.

Comment: @steve Thank you for your answer. Actually I would like to add a blank line before the first line.I think, my question was not clear.I have edited my question. sorry. If you can,please edit your answer.

Comment: @user1606106: I've updated my answer to add a blank line before the first line in a single file and for multiple files. HTH.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you a blank *space* at the start of your data file:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{printf(" ")}1' data.txt
```

Alternatively, this will give you a blank *line* at the start of your data file.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print""}1' data.txt
```

Comment: If you have GNU awk available `BEGINFILE` would be useful with multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `awk`:

```
echo -n ' ' | cat - file
```

Comment: Or `echo | cat - file` when adding a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0; print ""; next} NR==2{print a; print $0; next}1' file
```

For multiple files -

```
awk 'FNR==1{a=$0; print ""; next} FNR==2{print a; print $0; next}1' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. your code works perfectly for a single file. Could you help me to change the code for multiple files?

Comment: @user1606106 Sure just use `FNR` instead of `NR` for multiple files and pass each file at the end of the command.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I make the changes directly to the files?

Comment: @user1606106 `awk` does not offer infile substitution. You might have to do that in a loop and redirect to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

do it inline with perl:

```
perl -i -ne 'if(eof){$.=0;}if($.==1){print "\n";}print' temp temp2
```

temp and temp2 are two different files.after this command execution a blank line is automatically added to the start of each file.