# Adding new line to file with sed

Tags: text, awk, sed, scripting, newline

I want to add a new line to the top of a data file with sed, and write something to that line.

I tried this as suggested in [How to add a blank line before the first line in a text file with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658549/how-to-add-a-blank-line-before-the-first-line-in-a-text-file-with-awk) :

`sed '1i\
\' ./filename.txt`

but it printed a backslash at the beginning of the first line of the file instead of creating a new line. The terminal also throws an error if I try to put it all on the same line ("1i\": extra characters after \ at the end of i command).

Input :

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Expected output

```
14
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: sorry, more explanation now.

Comment: The awk works; thank you. Any idea why it doesn't work with sed ? My input is a text file with three numbers on each line, single spaced. I am trying to write a number on an empty new top line. The number instead is appended to the front of a number on the new line.

Comment: This corner of `sed` is poorly standardized; what works in one place won't work in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed '1i\14' file
14
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

but just use awk for clarity, simplicity, extensibility, robustness, portability, and every other desirable attribute of software:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print "14"} {print}' file
14
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: In this case I would suggest to use `sed`. What's the benefit of using `awk`? I mean you are *editing a stream*..

Comment: like I said, and I don't say it glibly - clarity, simplicity, extensibility, robustness, portability, and every other desirable attribute of software. There are many tools that can edit streams, awk included. You couldn't easily enhance/reuse the sed command to work for multiple lines or add conditions or do anything else but you could the awk command. I'm not even sure the sed command would work in all seds. sed is the best choice for simple substitutions on individual lines but, unlike when sed was invented in the early 1970s to be `ed` for streams, it's no longer the best for anything else.

Comment: I disagree here. The most robust solution for multiple lines, especially if the content to be concatenated is dynamic, is to use `cat`, that's why I've added that. Otherwise `sed` is perfect and meant for that purpose. There is a wide spectrum of tasks perfectly fitted for `awk`, I'm a big fan, but we don't need to use `awk` for everything it *can* do.

Comment: Let me admit that `awk '1' file1 file2` is as robust as `cat file1 file2`. But hey!, would you replace the `cat` command for that reason?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anyone use awk instead of cat. I'm stating that when you have to make simple substitutions on individual lines you should use sed but for any other text manipulation you should use awk because the end result will be better in many significant ways. Lets say the OP adopts the sed solution for this and then moves on to a similar-sounding problem and tries to adapt this solution. Chances are it'll need a complete rewrite given a tiny requirements change, unlike the awk which can doubtless be easily tweaked to work. You are of course welcome to disagree - happy seding!

Comment: `sed` is also perfect to delete lines. Some simple loops are better expressed in `sed`. And as you see, inserting a line at the top of a file is also best expressed with `sed`. Again, I'm really a big fan of `awk` and use it really hard while I use `sed` not that much in scripts, but your sentence `but just use awk for clarity, simplicity, ... ` is IMHO wrong in this case.

Comment: And at the end, it's better to replace all that shell coding weirdness by a *real* programming language like Python, Ruby ... More and more I come to that conclusion, while still my heart is at that weirdness! :) I mean the best `awk`, `sed`, `jq`, ... solution will still live in the eco-system of the shell. Meaning no exceptions, no complex types poor control structures etc...

Comment: I can't help but feel `that shell coding weirdness` you're referring to comes from trying to use the wrong tool for the job. FWIW neither perl, python, nor ruby are available on many of the UNIX boxes I have to code for in commercial products and so far I haven't missed them but I suppose YMMV.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100804/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-ed-morton).

Comment: No, there's nothing left to say. I don't care what tool you use and I don't feel obligated to try to persuade anyone to do anything. I've stated my opinion and you've stated yours, that's all

Comment: Let me add just one another point. This is a reason why I still favor `sed` over `awk` sometimes, even if `sed` is more complicated in some cases: `sed` can change files in place, `awk` can't do that. But it's not a "battle" between `sed`, `awk`, `cat` or whatever. I just wanted to collect and express arguments.

Comment: No, **GNU** sed can change files in place, just like GNU awk can. The behavior isn't POSIX for either of them and neither of them actually change the file inplace of course, they just save you from naming the temp file. Note that when you use inplace editing with sed it creates an insidious change in seds behavior when running on multiple files. Google it if interested, otherwise just use awk :-).

Comment: Yesterday I've investigated a bit about *why* awk does not offer to change files in place and indeed, gawk > 4.3 offers that feature. However, it seems that the Linux distros are not shipping that version already. At least not by default. Ubuntu has 4.1.1, Gentoo has 4.0.2.

Comment: I'm well aware gawk has the feature, see http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/awk-i/2115144 for why it has it ;-). Whatever distros don't have gawk 4.3 are missing a lot of useful functionality - they'll catch up eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Basially you are concatenating two files. A file containing one line and the original file. By it's name this is a task for `cat`:

```
cat - file <<< 'new line'
# or 
echo 'new line' | cat - file
```

while `-` stands for *stdin*.

You can also use `cat` together with command substitution if your shell supports this:

```
cat <(echo 'new line') file
```

Btw, with `sed` it should be simply:

```
sed '1i\new line' file
```